# run exe from web page?

Tags: php, asp.net, iis-7, exe

I want to make a web page that lunches an exe on the server when loaded
i tried php:

`exec('filename');`
but this wont show the gui it only work with console apps
i also tried .net to do that it worked when debugging but not when using iis
any one can help me?

Comment: Are you trying to show the GUI to the browser?

Comment: Can you post the .NET Code you used?

Comment: Yeah, where is the GUI supposed to pop up? On the server?

Comment: Is this any kind of remote launcher for a desktop application (with a graphic GUI)?

Comment: I think you're missing some fundamental understanding of how the web works. Browsers aren't just little windows into someone else's desktop.

Comment: I know that the app should run on the server and the  web page is only a remote invocation

Comment: @Nathon Haha 'browsers aren't just little windows into someone else's desktop'. That made my day, good way to start the morning!

Answer (score 1):

What code did you use in .NET to execute exe? You should use Process class - check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=VS.100).aspx) - it also gives an example as to how to use the class to execute the exe. The class allows lot of option such as redirecting standard i/p, o/p. You can even use WaitForExit method to wait till the process is complete.

Comment: Not sure why you want to show GUI at server - it does not make sense. As far as why GUI does not get displayed is quite simple - web server runs as a service (under different account) on a server machine. Typically, a non-interactive desktop will be associated with services and GUI if any would get associated with that desktop and so will not be visible on any interactive session that you are using to log on to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the same thing using PHP:

```
exec('cmd.exe /c yourexename.exe',$data,$ret);
```

where `$data` is output array and `$ret` will retur  0 for successful execution and 1 for failure.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking for any language that has that capability, I know coldfusion can do that using:

```
<cfexecute
name="ApplicationName"
arguments="CommandLine Arguments"
OUTPUTfile="Output file name"
timeout="Timeout interval in seconds">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
exec();
system();
```

Allows you to execute external programs and get the console output